# Why does `awk NF=NF RS= OFS=,` works?

Tags: awk

To replace newlines with commas using `awk` you can use the two following invocations:

1. `awk -v RS= '{gsub(/\n/,",",$0); print}'`
2. `awk NF=NF RS= OFS=,`

I understand how invocation 1 work, but not how 2 does. To start, it does not follows usage syntax:

```
awk [OPTINS] [--] PROGRAM [FILE ...]
```

`awk` should interpret `NF=NF` as the program and `RS=` and `OFS=,` as two input files.

How does it work?

Comment: you're missing final `'` in your first example

Comment: It's an empty program; the three parameters set how input and output are handled, in particular the separators, so `\n` on input is taken as the separator and replaced with a different separator (comma `,`) on output

Comment: Neither of those scripts ONLY replaces newlines with commas, neither of them will replace ALL newlines with commas, and they aren't equivalent to each other. If you'd like to know how to replace all newlines with commas and nothing else then post a new question.

Comment: @EdMorton I know. Both have caveats. For example, the second one trims spaces and both of them will fail when encountering a double newline ("\n\n"). But they do fine for controlled inputs. For uncontrolled inputs I use a more robust `tr | sed` solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a niche little trick in awk, that forces you to re-build `$0` with the updated modifiers (in this case `RS` and `OFS`)

Remember that, the crux of the manipulation is done by setting of `RS=` and `OFS=,` which in plain words means, reset the default input record separator from newline to empty and set the output field separator to `,`, thereby converting the newlines to commas in the input.

But how would you let `awk` interpret it? Because there is no `pattern { action }` part applicable here. If you just use `1` as below implying a default true action for all lines, it doesn't work.

```
awk 1 RS= OFS=, file
```

It doesn't do anything because the fields `RS`, `OFS` apply when the input line is "modified" in someway. It could be even a dumb statement like rewrite `$1` i.e. `{ $1 = $1 }1` overwrite first column with itself. Understand what really happens under the hood is, as part of modifying `$1` i.e. the current line, you get to apply the values of `RS` and `OFS` which in case produce your desired effect.

The one you had shown is also something similar. `NF` is the number of columns in a line split by the default field separator. So you intentionally modify it to itself `NF=NF`, i.e. suggesting a rebuild, but the rebuilt line is basically the same, but with the updated modified values of `RS`, `OFS` or any configuration.

So any of the following are functionally, the same

```
awk NF=NF RS= OFS=,
awk '{ $1 = $1 }1' RS= OFS=,
```

Comment: The last example has made it clear. `NF=NF` is the program, `RS=` and `OFS=,` are variable assignments. To make it easier to understand, we can rewrite it as `awk -v RS= -v OFS=, 'NF=NF'`.

Comment: @massa: fixed typo meant it to be OFS

Comment: Now my question is why program `NF=NF` is understood by `mawk`, `gawk` and `busybox awk` but not by `original-awk`?

Comment: Well, am not into too much of history on that. But I guess should be a recent development

Comment: @massa "original awk" is also known as old, broken awk - almost nothing works in it and it must never be used.

Comment: @Inian the script with `NF=NF` doesn't quite reproduce the input, it'll delete empty lines and lines containing only space chars and convert tabs (or any other sequences of spaces) to the OFS value.